# compact function returning undefined

Tags: laravel

I have a variable which I'm trying to send to the view. If the main image exists then I will send it to the view, if it doesn't exist I will set it ""; I don't know why the code isn't working. Can anyone help to explain it to me?

```
foreach($post->images as $image){
    $images[] = $image->image;
       if(!empty($images[0])){
                $mainImage = $images[0];
            } else {
                $mainImage = null;
            }
        }
return view('pages.post', compact('post', 'tags', 'previous', 'next', 'related', 'latest', 'latestSideCol', 'mainImage'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if statement from the foreach statement

```
foreach($post->images as $image){
            $images[] = $image->image;

        }

        if(!empty($images[0])){
            $mainImage = $images[0];
        } else {
            $mainImage = null;
        }
```